# Making a function take only the first value from every pair present

Tags: c++, function, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I need to make a function take only the first value of every `std::pair` passed to its arguments.  Values passed that are not of type `std::pair` will be used unaltered.  My following solution only works for functions that takes two arguments.  I need to know how to generalize this to any number of arguments passed.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_first_type : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct has_first_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::first_type>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename R, typename T, typename U, typename = void> struct act_on_first;

template <typename R, typename T, typename U>
struct act_on_first<R, T, U, std::enable_if_t<has_first_type<T>::value && has_first_type<U>::value>> {
    template <typename F>
    static R execute (const T& t, const U& u, F f) {
        return f(t.first, u.first);
    }
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename U>
struct act_on_first<R, T, U, std::enable_if_t<has_first_type<T>::value && !has_first_type<U>::value>> {
    template <typename F>
    static R execute (const T& t, const U& u, F f) {
        return f(t.first, u);
    }
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename U>
struct act_on_first<R, T, U, std::enable_if_t<!has_first_type<T>::value && has_first_type<U>::value>> {
    template <typename F>
    static R execute (const T& t, const U& u, F f) {
        return f(t, u.first);
    }
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename U>
struct act_on_first<R, T, U, std::enable_if_t<!has_first_type<T>::value && !has_first_type<U>::value>> {
    template <typename F>
    static R execute (const T& t, const U& u, F f) {
        return f(t, u);
    }
};

struct foo {
    template <typename... Args>
    std::size_t operator()(Args&&...) { return sizeof...(Args); }  // Simple example only.
};

template <typename T, typename U>
std::size_t bar (const T& t, const U& u) {
    return act_on_first<std::size_t, T, U>::execute(t, u, foo());
}

// Testing
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::pair<int, bool> k = {3, true};
    std::pair<int, char> m = {5, 't'};
    std::cout << bar(k,m) << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << bar(k,5) << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << bar(3,m) << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << bar(3,5) << '\n';  // 2
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Write a transformer, that either gives you `.first` for pairs or just returns its argument:

```
template <typename T> T const& take_first(T const& x) { return x; }
template <typename T, typename U>
T const& take_first(std::pair<T, U> const& p) { return p.first; }

template <typename... Args>
std::size_t bar(Args const&... args) {
    return foo{}(take_first(args)...);
}
```

Comment: I knew this solution already, but there is some overhead in transforming each argument.  The solution I posted for two arguments works instantly, does it not?  Or perhaps the time complexity is the same?

Comment: @prestokeys What overhead?

Comment: @prestokeys It is unlikely there is significant performance penalties, if any

Comment: Ok.  I was hoping there was a generalization of my method, which I couldn't see.

Comment: @prestokeys I don't know why you would want such a thing?